# If object with class X also has class Y then do

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to perform action when `<figure>` with class `.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper` has another class alongside it - `.test`.

This `.test` class is placed there by another JavaScript powered button that's toggling the class in and out. So this event would need to continue listening.

```
if($( ".woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper" ).hasClass( "test" )){
console.log('Hello');
// I have the 'hidden' class
};
```

I feel this is something super easy and as a JS noob, I'm doing something super stupid/missing something.

Comment: Please, show us the whole code to give an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(document.querySelector('.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').classList.contains('test')){
  console.log('Hello');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
if($(".woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper.test" ).length > 0){
  console.log('Found Test Element');
}
```

This will select all elements with both classes, `woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper` and `test`.

You can also do something like.

```
$(".woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper").each(function(i, el){
  if($(el).hasClass("test")){
    console.log("Found Test, Index: " + i);
  }
});
```

This will iterate each element with class `woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper` and check if it has the `test` class. This is helpful when you want to perform an action on just those elements.

You can also use `.filter()` like this.

```
$(".woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper").filter(".test").css("background", "yellow");
```

There are lots of ways to find a specific element.